# Error in importing relu activation

Tags: python-3.x, deep-learning, keras, jupyter-notebook, theano

Notebook environment: Python3

```
if K.image_data_format() == 'channels_first':
    input_shape = (3, img_rows, img_cols)
else:
    input_shape = (img_rows, img_cols, 3)

model = Sequential()    
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape)
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))

model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2)))
```

Error:

```
File "<ipython-input-6-50fd40b32811>", line 21
    model.add(Activation('relu'))
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I have checked the keras documentaion for importing relu, and it's exctly the same. What went wrong in here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is correct, there is a missing character on the line above:

```py
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), input_shape=input_shape))
```

You can also specify the activation as part of the Conv2D layer:

```py
model.add(Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape))
```